# Glitch in CAPTCHA submission

Tags: bug, captcha

Today, while submitting an answer in SO, I got this CAPTCHA.

[image]

After entering the displayed number, it showed me this error.

[image]

So, I closed CAPTCHA submission form, but to my surprise found that the answer was already posted.

[image]

Possibly a bug? I have encountered this a couple of times before. But this time I made sure to take the screenshots and draw a freehand circle.

Comment: Are you __sure__ you are not a bot?