# Image captcha, not loading

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha

Never loads, after minutes, hours, days ...

[image]

when trying to post on dsp or quant

### edit

I was using https-everywhere extension, I disabled it, browsed to http://dsp.se and works

Comment: Be patient, robot.

Comment: Chrome 32, a normal network that usually works well

Comment: not a dupe but maybe related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216256/glitch-in-captcha-submission

Comment: @rene a yes! I get it I'm using https-everywhere extension since a fexwtime... surely the reason

Comment: https everywhere is a known issue...

Comment: though like the other Post link, it's not working back when disabled, I'll try later by restarting Chrome, not now I've a download, thanks

Comment: this is the most recent httpse everywhere post i could find http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215414/ssl-errors-on-stack-exchange  also have a look at this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites   there are still hurdles (I'm quoting Nick Craver)

Comment: Well, you disabled the extension but still surf the `https` site. Change the protocol to `http` and try again.

Comment: @Antony well caught :), *accepted*

Comment: I should have noticed the post editing tools were already different with https not supported problem, no picture uploading etc..