# CAPTCHA doesn't present words

Tags: feature-request, bug, area-51, captcha, ssl

I know there's a new invisible form of CAPTCHA, but I'm not sure what words should be entered.  Am I missing something?  [image: Oops! Those aren't the correct words! but no words are shown]

Browser logs: 
[image: Browser logs says loading failed]

This may or may not be due to the HTTPS issue reported [in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216538/image-captcha-not-loading) and/or [last summer](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27101/captcha-not-loaded-due-to-an-insecure-script) and left unaddressed.

If the issue can't be solved, at the very least, the CAPTCHA page should have some text pointing this out or directing people to a workaround. It's pretty terrible UX to just keep a user blocked out while saying "Oops! Those aren't the correct words."

Comment: You browse `https://area51.stackexchange.com/` or `http://area51.stackexchange.com/`?

Comment: I was probably on the https version.

Comment: Nice try, robot.

Comment: I am *beep* not a robot.  And I do *beep* not have the hiccups.

Answer (score 2):

OK, the source of the bug appears to be this code block in Area 51 HTML source code for the [captcha page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/captcha):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6LduHQgAAAAAAGeXUpgp89IxHgHGOaV8MH6kHHem">

</script>
```

Since Area51 moved to https, this now cause a "mixed content" error in modern browsers.

Comment: +1. The solution is then just to drop "http:" from that URL in the page source so that the protocol defaults to what is being used on the current page (assuming ReCAPTCHA supports HTTPS, which appears to be the case).

Comment: @WBT yeah, this would work. But there's a good chance they won't touch the code, Area 51 code is pretty much obsolete as whole, from what I saw they touch it only in extreme cases.

Comment: Yep.  Well, the UX is pretty terrible, as noted above.

Comment: @WBT well, that's what happens when you don't improve anything on a site for long years, and let it decay slowly but surely.